# Android BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() does not refresh view

Tags: java, android, gridview, refresh, listadapter

I have a `GridView` with a `BaseAdapter` attached to it. The `GridView` itself is enclosed in a `ViewFlipper`.

I display the `GridView` by calling the `setDisplayedChild()` method on the `ViewFlipper`, then I update the dataset checked by the `BaseAdapter` and finally I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.
It usually does not refresh the `GridView` with the new content, or sometimes, it randomly refresh it, so it appears unpredictable.

I noticed that when I rotate my device to a new orientation, the view refresh itself and load the adapter data correctly. The same happened when the device goes standby and I unlock it, the view is magically refreshed with the new data.

I've tried to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `UIThread`, I tried to force view refresh by calling `forceLayout()`, `requestLayout()`, `invalidate()`, `invalidateChildren()` and so on, but nothing changes.

Even if I call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` from a button nothing happens, just rotating the device or locking and unlocking it refreshes the view.

I'm developing on a Asus tablet with Android 3.2.

Can someone help me or give me some hint?

Thank you very much!

Comment: After putting some log, i noticed that when the view doesn't refresh itself, the adapter methods getCount(), getView(), and so on aren't called at all. But when i "rotate" my device or i lock/unlock the screen, they're invoked, and the view refreshes.

Comment: SOLVED: the problem was ViewFlipper. I put the GridView on another activity and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your View is not Refreshing by using all of above then you have to redraw your grid view or you can do one thing when you set adapter of your grid put that lines on Resume method and call onResume() after made changes in your data.

Comment: redrawing GridView resulted in a black screen (i made another instance of GridView with same adapter, removed the old and added the new, but the new one isn't displayed leaving black. I tried the resume method but with no results.

Comment: SOLVED: the problem was ViewFlipper. I put the GridView on another activity and everything works fine.